# Energy of UV Light

Tags: energy, atmospheric-science

How much energy does UV light, in the atmosphere, exert?

For example, I know that CFCs were outlawed because the UV light was providing sufficient energy (BDE) to break the chlorine bonds and create chlorine radicals which wipe out ozone.
Therefore, is it possible to determine the amount of energy, in kJ or some other quantifiable unit, UV light can exert (specifically on molecules in the atmosphere)?

Answer (score 0):

It's need to be above UV C light, so above 10ev (see Wikipedia). So it's not from the order of kJ. Maximally it can reach around 100eV.

Namely the energy is always given by $$E=h \cdot f$$ where $f$ is the frequency and $h$ the Planck constant. So you can take frequency of the UV light and put it in. That's basically it, if you don't want to consider hard calculations with molecular vibrations etc.

Comment: So the energy ~ Planck's constant * 8 * ((10^15) hertz) = 5.30085603 × 10-18 joules?     Although I’m not contesting the validity of your answer, that seems like very little energy to break apart CFC compounds among the other BDEs it provides.